# Singleton problems with Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, singleton

After updating to XCode 7.3 and Swift 2.2, everything with my iOS project seemed fine and I have no compile errors or warnings. It worked perfectly when compiling to Swift 2.1

However, after the update, as soon as the app launches, it freezes and XCode returns an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, with no messages on the console. The problem is with my 'sharedInstance' singleton, for some reason it won't work.

The code goes as follows:

```
class Authenticator {
    private init() {}

    static let sharedInstance = Authenticator()

    private let parseDAO = ParseDataAccessObject.sharedInstance

    var place: Place?
    var placeObj: PFObject?
    var menu: Menu?
    var consumables: [Consumable]?
    var tables: [Table]?

    ....
}
```

When the app launches, it returns the following error:

[Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVYIb.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXDMe.png)

Answer (score 2):

Are one of the types of those properties an enum with a single case? There is a bug with the newest version of Swift that causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when an object is initialized with a single-case enum property that is not optional. Here is the relevant Swift bug tracker issue: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1035

For a temporary fix, add another case to the enum.